# web.config redirect not working on localhost

Tags: asp.net, azure, web-config, azure-web-app-service

I have a website that I work on in visual studio and then deploy to azure. I'd like to create a permanent redirect in my web.config file. I would like to test this to make sure it works before I deploy to azure.

Here is my web.config file

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="301Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*/PEOs.aspx" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://myblogpost.com" redirectType="Permanent"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

So when the user visits `www.mysite.com/PEOs.aspx` they will be directed to my blog post. The problem is, when I test this, it just goes to the page. Doesn't redirect. I realize I could just write some code in the code behind file, but I want something that's more SEO friendly.

Am I doing something wrong here? I'm fairly certain regex can be used here. But when I replaced it with `http://localhost:21537/PEOs.aspx` it doesn't work either. I don't want to publish to azure unless I know that this will only be an issue during local testing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using: `<match url="PEOs.aspx" />`

I was not entirely sure so I checked it here: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/rewrite-urls-from-aspnet-on-cloud-sites/

Comment: Yeah but I want to know why mine isn't working. Seems like I've followed what I need to.

Comment: Wow. that worked. Weird. I thought for sure I'd have to consider the entire url. I will accept your answer when I can.

Comment: I edited my answer so that the solution is in the answer.